# Converting a Dataframe Column of Dictionaries into New Columns based on Keys

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a Pandas dataframe column that consists of several dictionaries in the format of:

`df[students] = {u'51': [u'1592', u'1582', u'1272', u'459', u'1254', u'1267'], u'32': [u'1659', u'1322', u'1396', u'1315', u'1342', u'1661']} {u'51': [u'1592', u'1582', u'1272', u'459', u'1254', u'1267'], u'32': [u'1659', u'1322', u'1396', u'1315', u'1342', u'1661']}`
... and so on for several more entries.

Each dictionary represents one entry in the dataframe. I would like to convert this column into 2 new columns where the keys (51 and 32) are the column headers, and the values go into each column accordingly. I used the `df.to_list()` and `Pd.Series()` methods which seemed to work at first, but when I replicated it, it didnt change the data at all. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Do dictionaries all have the same keys? and do you want to stack list of for example key 51 from all dictionaries into a single column?

Answer (score 0):

why not just do:

```
df['51'], df['32'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: (x['51'], x['32']))

>>> print(df[['51','32']])
                                     51                                    32
0   (1592, 1582, 1272, 459, 1254, 1267)   (1592, 1582, 1272, 459, 1254, 1267)
1  (1659, 1322, 1396, 1315, 1342, 1661)  (1659, 1322, 1396, 1315, 1342, 1661)
```

Comment: Just tried it, got the 'string indices must be integers, not str' error.

Comment: try x[51] and x[32]

Comment: too many values to unpack now. Im working with a pretty big dataset

Comment: im not sure.. I copied and pasted your OP code unless something is different it should work

Comment: the dataframe I'm using has 28 other columns, but that shouldnt have an impact as the only one I want to manipulate is the one with all the dictionaries in it. Some of the dictionaries are of shorter lengths than the others (less values) but I can't imagine that would cause an issue

Comment: take a slice of your dataframe to work on and do .to_csv() and paste it for us, then we can recreate your dataframe using pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(the_string))

Comment: I would, only its stuff im not supposed to share. I posted the first few entries with the numbers changed, hoping that the solutions you guys posted would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the above methods posted didn't work while the strings in question were in unicode.

This finally worked:

`df['students'] = df['students'].map(eval)`

`df2 = pd.concat([df.drop('students', axis=1), pd.DataFrame(df['students'].tolist())], axis=1)`

I appreciate the answers posted, thanks a bunch everyone.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (you can convert **ANY** number of dictionaries with **ANY** sets of keys with this. If a key is missing in any dict, it will assign NaN to that cell):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df2 = json_normalize(df['students'])
```

df2:

```
                                    51                                    32
0  [1592, 1582, 1272, 459, 1254, 1267]  [1659, 1322, 1396, 1315, 1342, 1661]
1  [1592, 1582, 1272, 459, 1254, 1267]  [1659, 1322, 1396, 1315, 1342, 1661]
```